# Primefaces: OrderList fills backend list with String instead of Object

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my backend view, I have a list of some POJO:

**BackingView.java**

```
@Getter @Setter private List<SomePOJO> pojoList = ...
```

**SomePojo.java**

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, of = {"id"})
public class SomePojo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Getter @Setter private Long id;
    @Getter @Setter private Long date;
    @Getter @Setter private Date name;
    ....
    
  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return String.format("%s[id=%s]", getClass().getSimpleName(), id);
  }

  //making a readable string-representation of the object to display on the orderList
  public String toStringOrderlistDisplay() {
      return "Pojo with id " + id + "and so on... " 
  }
```

This list acts as you would expect in all regards. Recently, I wanted to add a feature to my frontend which allows the user to manually order this list. For that purpose I use Primefaces [OrderList](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/orderList.xhtml?jfwid=c06a9), like this:

**Frontend.xhtml**

```
<p:orderList id="ordList" widgetVar="ordList"
                                     value="#{backingview.pojoList }" var="rfg"
                                     controlsLocation="left"  responsive="true" itemValue="#{rfg}"
                                     itemLabel="#{rfg.toStringOrderlistDisplay()}">
    
</p:orderList>
```

As soon as I add the above p:orderList to my .xhtml file, I can see when inspecting in debug mode that `pojoList` no longer contains instances of `PojoClass` but rather plain strings (to be more precise, the string representation of the PojoClass-Object (What the toString() method would return)).
If I simply remove the orderList this problem does not occur. What is going on here? How is such a thing even possible in Java?

Comment: You need a converter. See the Advanced example at https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/orderList.xhtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using a converter as shown here [CountryConverter.java](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/primefaces-showcase/src/main/java/org/primefaces/showcase/convert/CountryConverter.java), and it worked.

Maybe when you don't specify a convertor, it uses a default `.toString()` implementation and can't serialize back to a `PojoClass`.

You can submit an issue [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/new/choose) to see if it's a bug.